# Displaying six graphs in two columns

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to display six graphs in two columns on a page. They are the graphs of various sets.  I would like the first column to be flush with the left margin. Since these graphs are solutions to a problem, I would like to display "4.) a.) set_1", "c.) set_2", and "e.) set_3" along the left margin. I guess displaying these in the upper left corner of each graph would look good.  Maybe above each graph.  I have seen solution manuals present it in both ways.  Same thing for second column.  I guess second column should be flush with right margin.  Any other opinions?

I included the codes for each graph.  I do not know whether they should all be in one TikZ environment. It does not display as I would like it to be displayed, but the sets to be displayed are there, and the code for graphing each set is there except for the hatching - a particular kind of shading - for b.) and e.).  I looked on page 217 of tikzpgfmanual.pdf
for drawing diagonal hatch lines.  They are not there, and I didn't see any examples of drawing hatch lines outside or inside a circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}


{\bf 4.) a.)} $\{z \mid \vert z – 1 + i \vert = 1\}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] y$};
  \draw[help lines] (1,-1) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

{\bf b.)} $\{z \mid \vert z + i \vert < 3\}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] y$};
  \pscircle[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 4pt,linewidth=0.5pt](0,-1) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}

{\bf c.)} $\{z \mid {\mathrm{Re}}\bigl(\overline{z} - i\bigr) = 2\}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] y$};
  \draw[help lines] (0,-1) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}

{\bf d.)} $\{z \mid \vert z – i \vert = \vert z + i \vert \}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] y$};
  \draw[line width=12] (0,0) (-1.75,0) -- (1.75,0);

{\bf e.)} $\{z \mid \vert z \vert > 1\}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] y$};
  \pscircle[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 4pt,linewidth=0.5pt](0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}


{\bf f.)} $\{z \mid z^{5} = 1\}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] y$};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,5 } {\node[dot,label={\i*360/5 -(\i==5)*45:$w_{\i}$}] (w\i) at (\i*360/5:1) {};
    \draw[->] (O) -- (w\i);
  }
  \draw[->] (0:.3) arc (0:360/5:.3);
  \node at (360/5 /2:.5) {${\scriptscripttyle{72^{\circ}}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post a working code and let us know the compiler you use (`latex`, `pdflatex`, etc)? For instance, I find several problems with your `tikzpictures` and `pscircle` is undefined...

Answer (score 1):

Although I had to comment out some code and fix some typos, the below code nonetheless achieves what I think is your objective. I also changed `\bf` to `\bfseries` per the comment from Gonzalo. It uses the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package to put floats in two columns. I also adjusted the margins so that it would fit better, but you'd probably be better off adjusting the size of the figures. Hope it helps!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{}{
{\bfseries 4.) a.)} $\{z \mid \vert z - 1 + i \vert = 1\}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
  \draw[help lines] (1,-1) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\par

{\bfseries b.)} $\{z \mid \vert z + i \vert < 3\}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] {$y$};
  % \pscircle[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 4pt,linewidth=0.5pt](0,-1) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\par

{\bfseries c.)} $\{z \mid {\mathrm{Re}}\bigl(\overline{z} - i\bigr) = 2\}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[left] {$y$};
  \draw[help lines] (0,-1) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\hfill

\ffigbox{}{
{\bfseries d.)} $\{z \mid \vert z – i \vert = \vert z + i \vert \}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
  \draw[line width=12] (0,0) (-1.75,0) -- (1.75,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\par

{\bfseries e.)} $\{z \mid \vert z \vert > 1\}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
  % \pscircle[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 4pt,linewidth=0.5pt](0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\par

{\bfseries f.)} $\{z \mid z^{5} = 1\}$\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$x $};
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,5 } {\node[dot,label={\i*360/5 -(\i==5)*45:$w_{\i}$}] (w\i) at (\i*360/5:1) {};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (w\i);
  }
  \draw[->] (0:.3) arc (0:360/5:.3);
  \node at (360/5 /2:.5) {${\scriptstyle{72^{\circ}}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: As usual, `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`.

Comment: I tried compiling the code on two computers. On my computer, I got the error "LaTeX Error: File 'floatrow.sty' not found." On another computer, I got the error "I can't find file `tikzlibraryangles.code.tex'."

Comment: In the first case you are missing the `floatrow` package - how to install this depends on which TeX distribution you have installed. In the second, you appear to be missing some libraries. You should re-install the `tikz` package.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "TeX distribution".  I am using MikTeX to compile the code on both computers.  The editor that my computer has installed is WinEdt.  I just looked. I do have "\usepackage{floatrow}" in the preamble.

Comment: I put "%" before the commands "\begin{floatrow}" and "\end{floatrow}" to look at the graphs. In a.) you have "$\{z \mid \vert z – 1 + i \vert = 1\}$" in the code, but the display is "|z1 + i| = 1". What happened to the minus sign? In b.), only the coordinates axes are drawn. In c.), the graph for b.) is drawn. (I guess deleting the floatrow command did this.) I wanted the circle to be dashed and I wanted diagonal hatch lines in the circle. (Look at the set.)  Graphs for e.) and f.) are missing, but you have the code for them. (For graph in e.), I wanted shading outside the circle.)

Comment: I copied exactly your code, except I had to fix several typos (like missing `{$` on all the lines with `{$y$}` and a missing `\end{tikzpicture}`) and comment out the `pscircle` lines. Any other errors are errors that you introduced into the code when you copied it into the question. See [here](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) to see how to install packages for MiKTeX. Make sure to choose the "Administrator" version of the package manager.

Comment: I will try to install floatrow package. How is that used in the code?  LaTeX is not compiling some of the code.  As I said, in a.), LaTeX is not typesetting a minus sign. The code is "$\{z \mid \vert z – 1 + i \vert = 1\}$" but the display is "{z | |z1 + i| = 1".  Three of the graphs are missing.

Comment: The floatrow package is what adds the `\begin{floatrow}` environment. Basically, it enables multiple floats in one row. Have a look at the [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow). The issue with the minus sign is that you've used the en-dash character, instead of minus. Try deleting it and typing it again, or copy the code out of my post. I don't know about missing graphs, all six show up in my output.